# How to get the last Axios call of a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a JS function that executes when a user click on an image and call an axios request to my backend and get a price, the problem is that the user can click different images at any time and the backend takes 5-10 seconds to get back the response and the price is updated many times because the user could be clicked 5 different images (block images is not an option).

How can I solve to only get the price of the last image that user clicked and ignore other requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From version v0.22.0 Axios support AbortController to cancel requests. You could first create an abort controller which you abort before fetching a new request. Something like this:

```js
const controller = new AbortController();

function handleClick(){

  // cancel the request
  controller.abort();

  axios.get('/foo/bar', {
     signal: controller.signal
  }).then(function(response) {
     //...
  });
}
```

Checkout the oficial Axios [docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation) on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You could [debounce](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/debouncing-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=Debouncing%20in%20JavaScript%20is%20a,is%20a%20single%20threaded%20language.) the function making the request.
Debouncing sets a timer on a function that gets reset on subsequent calls of that specific function in the set time frame.

Here I used the debounce function provided by [underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/#debounce)

```
handleClick () {
  _.debounce(loadData, 300); // Debounce calls to load data by 300ms
}

loadData () {
  // sends the axios request to fetch pricing info
}
```

For example:
The user clicks on an image, `handleClick` is called. If the user does not click again on any image within 300ms `loadData`is called and the request is excecuted.

If the user does click an image within the specified 300ms the time starts again; Thus, only the last click in the given time frame counts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [abort controller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort) to cancel the request when the user clicks on another image.